# Use grams and kgs as quantity for enhanced ecommerce in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

In one of our ecommerce system we have products in which we use grams or kilograms as the quantity. i.e. we can buy 500 gm of X products with price, say, 2 euros per kg, then on google analytics, the revenue is calculated as `500 * 2 = 1000` euros. Which is incorrect as the actual revenue should have been just 1 euro. The revenue is falsely maximized. 
We tried sending the quantity as 0.5 but google analytics accepts integer value only for quantity. 
Is there a way we can send grams or kgs as quantity or use decimal values?

Comment: If these are discrete units you could define the smallest possible unit (i.e. 500g) as quantity 1 and track larger packages as multiple units (i.e. one kg would be quantity 2).  But I don't think there is a really good solution.

Answer (score 2):

No. Unfortunately, you have to live with this. I work on a site where we receive around £0.01 per click, but Google has to believe that it's £1. It's an issue, but you simply have to accept that it's giving you 100x (or 1000x) the actual number. So long as everybody using the account understands the convention, you're fine.

Or, if it really bugs you, you could create a Calculated Metric 'Actual Value' that divides the value by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: recalculate your price unit to ***X per gram***, then have grams as the base quantity. That way your revenue remains correct, just your quantity inflates..